# Codeigniter PHP sessions not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I'm working on a website in CodeIgniter framework and I tried to make some sessions for the admin and the users. But when I try to use those sessions they aren't working properly. When I'm logged out I'm getting errors that i can't find the session called:   `$_SESSION['user_level']`

Also when I'm logged out and I click on the login form view page I get this error without doing anything:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Filename: controllers/Auth.php

Line Number: 80

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Auth.php
Line: 80
Function: session_start

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

This is my controller auth.php with the functions of user login, admin login, and logout. :

```
public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect("https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/", "refresh");
    } 


    public function adminlogin() 
    {
        session_start();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin_email', 'Admin_email', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin_wachtwoord', 'Wdmin_wachtwoord', 'required|min_length[5]');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            $admin_email = $_POST['admin_email'];
            $admin_wachtwoord = ($_POST['admin_wachtwoord']);

             //check admin in database
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('admin');
            $this->db->where(array('admin_email'=>$admin_email, 'admin_wachtwoord' => $admin_wachtwoord));
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $admin = $query->row();

              //Als admin bestaat
            if($admin->admin_email) {

                $this->session->set_flashdata("success","U bent nu ingelogd als admin");

            //Maak admin sessions aan
            $_SESSION['user_logged'] = FALSE; 
            $_SESSION['admin_logged'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['is_logged'] = true.
            $_SESSION['user_level'] = 10;
            $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $admin->admin_id;
            $_SESSION['admin_email'] = $admin->admin_email;


             //link naar profiel pagina
            redirect("IndexController", "refresh");
            } else {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid email or password');
                //wanneer er een foutmelding is link weer naar de login pagina
                redirect("https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/adminlogin" , "refresh");
            }

            }
              //laad alle adminlogin views
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('adminviews/adminlogin');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }




    public function login()
    {
        //laad login view
            session_start();
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('wachtwoord', 'Wachtwoord', 'required|min_length[5]');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $wachtwoord = ($_POST['wachtwoord']);


            //check gebruiker in database
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->where(array('email'=>$email, 'wachtwoord' => $wachtwoord));
            $query = $this->db->get();

            $user = $query->row();
            //Als gebruiker bestaat
            if($user->email) {

                $this->session->set_flashdata("success","U bent nu ingelogd");

            $_SESSION['user_logged'] = TRUE; 
            $_SESSION['admin_logged'] = FALSE;
            $_SESSION['is_logged'] = true.
            $_SESSION['user_level'] = 1; 
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->user_id;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $user->email;
            $_SESSION['voornaam'] = $user->voornaam;
            $_SESSION['achternaam'] = $user->achternaam;
            $_SESSION['woonplaats'] = $user->woonplaats;
            $_SESSION['straat'] = $user->straat;
            $_SESSION['huisnummer'] = $user->huisnummer;
            $_SESSION['postcode'] = $user->postcode;
            $_SESSION['beschrijving'] = $user->beschrijving;
            $_SESSION['profiel_foto'] = $user->profiel_foto;




            //link naar profiel pagina
            redirect("user/profile", "refresh");
            } else {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Invalid email or password');
                //wanneer er een foutmelding is link weer naar de login pagina
                redirect("https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/login" , "refresh");
            }



            }
                  //laad login view
                  $this->load->view('loginregistreer');
    }
```

This is some code in my header to echo some buttons with the sessions I created:

```
<li> 
<?php 
if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1): ?> 
<a class="l3" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/user/profile">Account</a> 
<?php endif;?> 
</li> 
<li> 
<?php if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 10):?> 
<a class="l3" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/IndexController">Admin dashboard</a> 
<?php endif; ?> 
</li> 
<li> 
<?php if($_SESSION['user_level'] <= 10):?> 
<a class="l4" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/logout">Uitloggen</a> 
<?php else: ?> 
<a class="l5" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/register">Registreren</a> 
</li><li> 
<a class="l6" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/login">Inloggen</a> 
<?php endif ;?> 
</li>
```

It works so when I'm logged in as an admin it shows the correct buttons in the header but when I logout I'm getting this error 3 times on every page where I included the header:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: user_level

Filename: templates/header.php

Line Number: 31

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/templates/header.php
Line: 31
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/home.php
Line: 1
Function: include_once

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Site.php
Line: 9
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting those errors?

Comment: Try looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `session_start();` from your code, codeigniter session library takes care of it.

First you have to load session library.

```
$this->load->library("session");
```

if you have loaded already in autoload config then no need of loading again.

To set data in session

```
$this->session->set_userdata("KEY","VALUE");
```

To get data from session

```
$this->session->userdata("KEY");
```

Read more from here :

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: thanks, it working my project

Comment: please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You're doing all wrong.

**Set session should be**

```
$newdata = array(
        'user_logged'  => TRUE,
        'admin_logged'     => FALSE,
        'logged_in' => TRUE
        ......
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

**Retrivng**

```
$this->session->userdata('admin_logged');
```

---

**Load library**

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

---

[Read this `Using the Session Class`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#id3)

Comment: regular php should also work?

Comment: then what this `$this->session->sess_destroy();` and `session_start();` use one either CI or either pure one

Comment: i removed session start so now it should work but it doesn't

Comment: reformat the code as it said

Comment: any update on this

Comment: It works already thanks for helping :) the errors were caused because I didn't use isset